# Apply 2 different textures to two sides of the same face of an object in Autodesk Maya

Tags: maya, autodesk

I've been trying to apply 2 separate textures to the inside and outside of a bowl shaped object in Maya. I don't want to extrude that particular face and put a different texture. That's easy though.

But since I'm working on a low-res model where I'm restricted to have a certain number of faces, so I need an alternative. Someone gave me an idea of using Maya Nodes. But, I couldn't come up with a solution.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you see this: https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-E4CA98D6-ACF8-4B97-BE9D-4E69A2275A37

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using samplerInfo node.
Just put a switch or colorBlend and use flippedNormal as a switcher between 2 textures/shaders/w/e is it.